# Simple app, but would like to correctly manage my SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i am developing a simple app to learn more about Android. While progressing, i'm trying to make it a little better, but i must say i'm very confused about the database management.

My database is very simple: a single table with just 4 columns.

What i have so far:

1) A pretty standard SQLiteOpenHelper-derived class, named MySQLiteHelper

2) A model class, named Entry, representing the contents of a row

3) A DAO class:

```java
public class EntriesDataSource {
    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private Context context;

    private String[] allColumns = { 
                    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
                    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ENTRY_TYPE,
                    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACTUAL_ENTRY,
                    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER_EDITED_ENTRY };

    public EntriesDataSource(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    //.... Just showing some methods here, to give an idea .....

    public int updateDescription(long id, long entryType, String newDescription) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER_EDITED_ENTRY, newDescription);

        if(entryType == MySQLiteHelper.ENTRY_TYPE_PURE_TEXT)
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ACTUAL_ENTRY, newDescription);

        return database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ENTRIES, values,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }

    public Cursor getAllEntries() {
         return database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ENTRIES,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER_EDITED_ENTRY + " Collate NOCASE");
    }
}
```

4) I created my own Application-derived class, in which i do have a EntriesDataSource object, which i create in the Application's onCreate method:

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static EntriesDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        datasource = new EntriesDataSource(this);

    }

    public int updateDescription(long entryId, long entryType,
        String newDescription) {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        datasource.open();
        rowsAffected = datasource.updateDescription(entryId, entryType,
            newDescription);
        datasource.close();

        return rowsAffected;
    }

    public Cursor getAllEntries() {
        datasource.open();
        Cursor cursor = datasource.getAllEntries();
        //datasource.close();
        return cursor;
    }
```

5) A ListActivity displaying all the items. So far, i had used an ArrayAdapter. Today i decided to try with a custom CursorAdapter, so i adopted an approach like the following, inspired by the Busy Coder's guide to Android:

```java
    public class ManageEntriesActivity extends ListActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_entries);

                new LoadCursorTask().execute();
        }



    private class LoadCursorTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Cursor entriesCursor=null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      entriesCursor=MyApplication.getInstance().getAllEntries();
      entriesCursor.getCount();

      return(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void arg0) {
      ManageEntriesCustomCursorAdapter adapter;

        adapter=
            new ManageEntriesCustomCursorAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    entriesCursor,
                                    0);

      setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
  }
```

As you can notice, i used to open the db connection, do stuff with it, then close it immediately. That worked fine with the ArrayAdapter approach, but it doesn't with the CursorAdapter, since i need a "live" cursor for it: that's why i commented out the db.close() in the getAllEntries method.

This "asymmetry", though, makes me wonder if i will get in trouble later, since it seems at least odd that there's a place in which i open the db and i leave it like that, while for every other access to it i will close it too. I did try to search online for a best practice, but it only added to the confusion, since i found some alternatives:

- just open the database and leave it open (apparently the SQLiteOpenHelper will take care of correctly closing it)
- Open and close it as soon as you can
- Wrap it in a ContentProvider, which will take care of everything

What could be the best strategy in my case? Also, if you find something in my code is weird, please point it out :-)

Thanks in advance!